# What does \ (backslash) mean in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-like

I have the following query

```
SELECT txt1 FROM T1 WHERE txt1 LIKE '_a\%'
```

will that result in answers that have any char+a+\+whatever?

is something like Pa\pe valid as a result?

are Ca% or _a% valid answers maybe?

how does \ behave normally inside an SQL query??

Comment: Most often, it is an escape character, saying interpret the next character as a literal, not a wild card character...

Comment: so it should produce results like Ca% or _a%?

Comment: The above is wrong for tSQL in MSSQL. The backslash "\" character has no special meaning there. USE ESCAPE 'x' to define x as the escape character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

% is a wildcard character that matches zero or more characters in a LIKE clause.
_ is a wildcard character that maches exactly one character in a LIKE clause.

\ is a special character known as an escape character that indicates that the character directly following it should be interpreted literally (useful for single quotes, wildcard characters, etc.).

For example:

```
SELECT txt1 FROM T1 WHERE txt1 LIKE '_a%'
```

will select records with txt1 values of 'xa1', 'xa taco', 'ya anything really', etc.

Now let's say you want to actually search for the percent sign. In order to do this you need a special character that indicates % should *not* be treated as a wildcard. For example:

```
SELECT txt1 FROM T1 WHERE txt1 LIKE '_a\%'
```

will select records with txt1 values of 'ba%' (but nothing else).

Finally, a LIKE clause would typically contain a wildcard (otherwise you could just use = instead of LIKE). So you might see a query containing \%%. Here the first percent sign would be treated as a literal percent sign, but the second would be interpreted as a wildcard. For example:

```
SELECT txt1 FROM T1 WHERE txt1 LIKE '_a\%%'
```

will select records with txt1 values of 'da%something else', 'fa% taco', 'ma% bunch of tacos', etc.

Comment: ok, but _ will still select any char right? so then LIKE '_a\%' actually results in stuff like 'Xa\%' being X any char (anything actually)?

Comment: Yes. _ is a wildcard character that matches any single character. % will match multiple characters.

Comment: are both 'Ca%' and '_a%' valid query results for SELECT txt1 FROM T1 WHERE txt1 LIKE '_a\%' then?

Comment: Yes. The _ wildcard will match any single character, including the _ literal. I'd recommend trying this sort of thing out in a local database. There is no substitute for some good, old-fashioned trial and error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the most detailed explanation to me ^^

Answer (score 4):

The LIKE clause allows you to find text when you don't know the exact value, such as names beginning with JO would be

```
LIKE 'JO%'
```

However, if you are search for something ending with **`a%`**, then you need to tell SQL to treat the % as part of what you are searching for.   In your example, you are looking for a 3 character string, you don't care what the first letter is, but has to end with **a%**.

Comment: like 'JO%' will find words starting with JO, my doubt is not about the use of %, but the use of the backslash

Comment: do you know anything about \ ??

Comment: Which SQL are you using (Microsoft, Oracle, mySQL, etc.)

Comment: none, it's a question from a test :/ it's just a generic query

Comment: Not sure what \?? means, sorry

Comment: Also, the single underscore character (`_`) is a special wildcard character, meaning it will match any single character in the string.

Comment: @Polux Read Sparky's answer more carefully; the backslash is likely an escape character so the percent sign is treated as part of the search string and not a wildcard.  In other words, it would match a value like **Xa%** (the percent sign part of the value itself).

Comment: Anything written here that backslash ("\") has a special meaning in MSSQL tSQL is incorrect. The examples that show backslash as a special escape character are incorrect (try them!) The proper way to escape something like the percent sign in tSQL is with ESCAPE, which permits defining the escape character (tSQL has no default escape character). For example, SELECT txt1 FROM T1 WHERE txt1 LIKE '_a#%' ESCAPE '#'