# How to use a percent (%) in a LIKE without it being treated as a wildcard?

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have a database that is supposed to contain all top-level and second-level domain names. But the feed I'm parsing contains a lot of sub folders, I'd like to delete any row that contains any % sign in it, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to use a percent sign as the field I'd like to match, while still using the LIKE feature.  Below is the code I'm trying to use:

```
select FROM `001ProductList` WHERE programURL  LIKE '%%%'
```

Here is an example of what I'm trying to match:

> www.site.com%3Ack-5941560-10463497?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fproddetail.aspx%...

If I encounter a row with a % sign in it, I want to delete it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214509/what-does-backslash-mean-in-an-sql-query/15215106#15215106 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803489/sql-like-query-using-where-search-criteria-contains

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Escape the literal `%` character:

```
select * 
FROM 001ProductList
WHERE programURL LIKE '%\%%'
```

or use regex

```
WHERE programURL RLIKE '%'
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: @Bohemian `SELECT * 
FROM  `001ProductList` 
WHERE programURL LIKE  '%/%%'
LIMIT 0 , 30` selects everything in the table, including urls that don't contain percent signs.

Comment: That's a *backslash* before the middle percent in the first version (your comment has a *forward* slash, which won't work), but I would use the second version too - easier to read because percent is not a special regex character (doesn't need escaping) and you need only code the percent because `RLIKE` only needs to *partially* match

Comment: You're right on the first one, my mistake.  Thank you greatly for the help mate!

Answer (score 3):

You may use the [`LOCATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) function, like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `001ProductList`
WHERE LOCATE('%', `programURL`) <> 0;
```