# How to search whole sentence form mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

This is my code

```
 $question = "What is your Name";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `def_questions` where `question` LIKE '$question' ";
```

it does not retun the exact result
I need exact ( What is Your Name ) will some body help me to do this.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: the same word for word and caps? What is the content of `question` column?

Comment: There are list of questions.

Comment: If you use this query in MySQL, does it work? Is there a row with the **exact** question?

Comment: ^ it matters if we know if the questions you need are on the list word for word.

Comment: Give [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) a read on how to use LIKE since you've used it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $question = rtrim(ltrim(strip_tags(What is your Name)));
$query = "SELECT * FROM `def_questions` where `question` LIKE '%$question%' ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding '%' before and after your variable as shown below.

```
$question = "What is your Name";
$query = "SELECT * FROM `def_questions` where `question` LIKE '%$question%' ";
```

**EDIT** To prevent SQL injection just do this:

```
$question = mysql_real_escape_string($question);
```

Comment: It gives the blank Array !

Comment: @SajidMehmood then I guess your database structure is different can provide your database structure and some rows maybe?

Comment: In phpmyadmin it working fine but when use query in php give no result

Comment: @Sajid Mehmood Could you show us your complete code? If you said it does work in phpmyadmin console then perhaps the problems occur in your php code.

Comment: Yes, if it is working fine on phpmyadmin then there is something wrong in your php code. As, the query works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code may be vulnerable for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use prepared statements for passing values to query:

```
$questions = Yii::$app->db
    ->createCommand("SELECT * FROM `def_questions` where `question` LIKE :question", [
        ':question' => "%$question%",
    ])
    ->queryAll();
```

Note that you should also escape some special characters from searched value, to make it work correctly with `LIKE` operator (for example treat `%` as `%` instead of "anything", see [How to use a percent (%) in a LIKE without it being treated as a wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749787/how-to-use-a-percent-in-a-like-without-it-being-treated-as-a-wildcard)):

```
$question = strtr($question, [
    '%' => '\%',
    '_' => '\_',
    '\\' => '\\\\',
]);
$questions = Yii::$app->db
    ->createCommand("SELECT * FROM `def_questions` where `question` LIKE :question", [
        ':question' => "%$question%",
    ])
    ->queryAll();
```

The easiest way to do the whole thing is probably by using [`Query`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query):

```
$questions = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->from('def_questions')
    ->where(['like', 'question', $question])
    ->all();
```

`Query` will do escaping for you and will return results for SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `def_questions` where `question` LIKE '%What is your Name%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want exact result, you can use = instead of LIKE

```
$question = "What is your Name";
$query = "SELECT * FROM `def_questions` where `question` = '$question'"
```