# ExecuteNonQuery : incorrect syntax near /

Tags: c#, sql-server

I get the following error and I have been trying to figure out what the problem is for a few weeks but nothing, could someone help ?

> An unhandled exception of type **`'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'`** occurred in `System.Data.dll`
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near **`'/'`**.

And here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Add_Position : Form
    {
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlDataAdapter da;

    public Add_Position()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'position_ListDataSet.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.position_ListDataSet.Table);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con=new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=sqlserver;Initial Catalog=Position_List;Integrated Security=False;User ID=administrator;Password=;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table (Name, Dwt, Built, Position, Area, L/C from, L/C to, Contact) Values (@Name, @Dwt, @Built, @Position, @Area, @L/C from, @L/C to, @Contact)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", nametxt.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Dwt", dwttxt.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Built", builttxt.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Position", postxt.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Area", areatxt.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@L/C from", lcftxt.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@L/C to", lcttxt.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Contact", contxt.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The error message tells you what's wrong - "L/C from" would need to be escaped to be specified as a column name. Personally I'd recommend renaming your columns to avoid spaces, punctuations and keywords though. Additionally, please note that you've specified a *lot* of irrelevant code here (all those empty event handlers, to start with)... in future, please try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: You can't name columns with slashes or spaces without escaping them. Ideally you shouldn't have to escape column names at all so change the names of those columns, specifically, the two columns "L/C from" and "L/C to" should be renamed to not contain slash nor space. Even just `L_C_from` is better though still not good, what does L and C stand for? Most likely there is a better name lurking behind those letters, remember that you don't have to save typing so be explicit with those names.

Comment: I suggest to change your column names and parameter names something meaningful that does not include ``\`` character. Read: [What does \ (backslash) mean in an SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15214509/447156)

Comment: Also please read some documentations about `using` statement and "connection pooling".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your column names in database `L/C from to LC_From`and `L/C T0 = LC_To`
I thing then i would not get any error .

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con=new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=sqlserver;Initial Catalog=Position_List;Integrated Security=False;User ID=administrator;Password=;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table (Name, Dwt, Built, Position, Area, LC_from, LC_to, Contact) Values (@Name, @Dwt, @Built, @Position, @Area, @LC_from, @LC_to, @Contact)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", nametxt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Dwt", dwttxt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Built", builttxt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Position", postxt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Area", areatxt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LC_from", lcftxt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LC_to", lcttxt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Contact", contxt.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

as adviced in comments and other answers,i also recommend you to change columnnames with /'s as it will give further unexpected erros.Though i can give another quick fix,ie In SQL Server, identifiers can be delimited using square brackets, e.g.

```
SELECT [table/1] ...
```

in you case,pls try using

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table (Name, Dwt, Built, Position, Area, [L/C from], [L/C to], Contact) Values (@Name, @Dwt, @Built, @Position, @Area, @L/C from, @L/C to, @Contact)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", nametxt.Text);
```

hope this helps.